# How can I execute the code, after I return in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

Here is the things I need to do...

```
-(unsigned int)doSomething
{
    msg_id++;

    //something need to be done after returning
    //process

    return msg_id;
}

[somebody doSomething];
```

Now the process is like this:

1. `somebody` called `doSomething`
2. Process is executed
3. Msg id is returned

The flow I wanna:

1. `somebody` called `doSomething`
2. Msg id is returned
3. Process is executed

You can ask me to do when `somebody` `doSomething` is finished, but I can't change this part. I can only change the `doSomething` method. Also, some workaround suggestions is calling a delay after X seconds. But I concern the after delay X second. Because I don't know return `msg_id` need how many second, actually.
Any better suggestion?

Comment: I'm afraid your requirements are not very clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CS101. `return`, does just that. It returns. Perhaps, you want 'process' to be something that is done in the background, or on a separate thread? You might be looking at this then:

```
-(unsigned int)doSomething
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        //something need to be done after returning
        //process
    });

    return msg_id;
}
```

In any case, I think you need to rethink your logic.